# Java - find jar file of class (or classes directory)

Tags: java, url

I can request the URL for the jar file or classes directory where Java loaded a class from:

```
Class clazz = ...
URL url = clazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

but how to correctly convert this to a `File` (or `Path`) - especially with respect to some characters of the path escaped in URLs? I've tried this:

```
String fileName = URLDecoder.decode(url.getFile(), "UTF-8");
File jarFileOrClassesDir = new File(fileName);
```

but this causes problems if there is a `+` inside the path (the `+` is replaced with a space).

Comment: What is it that you want to do with the file?  Do you just need to access what is in the file?  Do you need to act on the file like move it around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
but this causes problems if there is a + inside the path (the + is replaced with a space).
```

This is standar behavior of `URLDecoder`. See more information at JavaDoc [1], plus (`+`) is mentioned there as well.

### Solution using `Paths`

Using `Paths#get(URI)` [2] should preserve all "special" symbols and you can pass directly `URI` which can be retrieved directly from `URL` using `URL#toURI()` [3].

So in summary:

```
final var filePath = Paths.get(url.toURI()); // We can extract any information from Path e.g. fileName.
```

shoud work as expected.

---

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLDecoder.html

[2] https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.net.URI)

[3] https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html#toURI()